# Keras -- Input Shape for Embedding Layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to implement a convolutional autoencoder in Keras with layers like the one below. My data has 1108 rows and 29430 columns.

```
def build(features, embedding_dims, maxlen, filters, kernel_size):
    m = keras.models.Sequential()

    m.add(Embedding(features, embedding_dims, input_length=maxlen))
    m.add(Dropout(0.2))

    m.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, input_shape=(len(xx), features) ))
    m.add(MaxPooling1D())

    m.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1, input_shape=(None, len(xx), features) ))
    m.add(UpSampling1D())

    m.summary()
    m.compile(optimizer="adagrad", loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return m

early = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=1, mode='min')

model = build(len(xx[0]), 60, 11900, 70, 3)

model.fit(xx, xx, batch_size=4000, nb_epoch=10000,validation_split=0.1, 
    callbacks=[early])
```

However, I get an error that states `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (None, 11900) but got array with shape (1108, 29430)`. Why would the first layer expect (None, maxlen) rather than the size of the data?

I'll also include my model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 11900, 60)         714000    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 11900, 60)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 11898, 70)         12670     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5949, 70)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 5947, 70)          14770     
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling1d_1 (UpSampling1 (None, 11894, 70)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 741,440
Trainable params: 741,440
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this particular error by adding an `input_shape` field to the Embedding layer as follows:

```
m.add(Embedding(features, embedding_dims, input_length=maxlen, input_shape=(features, ) ))
```

`features` is the number of features (29430).

Comment: What's the new model summary?

Answer (score 1):

Your input into the Embedding layer must be one dimensional, so you would need to reshape your data into this format (,n).  Whatever you passed into input_length would need to match the n size.